# what is the distribution of Proportion?

Tags: distributions, binomial-distribution

I have some observations are recorded as Proportion, from a binomial distribution with unknown success numbers. Typically in standard case, we observe only number of successes say $X$ out of trials say $N.$

But in my case, I just see the proportion of successes $P_i$ without knowing $X_i$ and $N_i$. So given I have sequence of data $P_1, P_2, \ldots$, what can be the theoretical distribution, given that the legitimate range for those observation is $0, 1$ inclusive?

Comment: The distribution of $P_i$ depends on $N_i$, so if the $N_i$ are different for different $i$, there isn't a single distribution in the first place, as the $P_i$ are not identically distributed. Furthermore, as long as the $N_i$ are not regularly repeating in some sense, distributions can change all the time even in directions where they hadn't been before.

Comment: The distribution of $P_i$ given $N_i$ is known, so if you have a prior distribution for $N_i$, you can compute an overall distribution for $P_i$. But without assuming anything about the $N_i$, there is no way. (This is the Bayesian answer, the first one was frequentist assuming the $N_i$ to be fixed.)

Comment: Scaled binomial. But if you don't know $X$ or $N$, you can only make guesses as to what they might be.

Comment: When you have an upper bound for each $N_i$ and the $P_i$ are recorded with sufficient precision, often you can recover the $N_i$ and the $P_iN_i$ from the mere fact that both must be non-negative integers.  I have done this to reverse-engineer data in a few questions here on CV (but, alas, it's not possible to search for them...)  The method is a brute-force search: multiply $P_i$ by all values of $N_i$ from $1$ through the upper bound and identify any results that are unusually close to integers.  Usually, choosing the smallest such $N_i$ leads to a conservative analysis.

Comment: My post at https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/309058/919 provides details of how to do such a search along with example code.